# How/When is my onReadyStateChange function running?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Let's suppose we have a function for getting some data from database:

```
function getResults() {
    if (httpReq.readyState == 4 || httpReq.readyState == 0) {
        httpReq.open("GET",'../search.php?blablabla',true);
        httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
                // Some code here
            }
        };
        httpReq.send(null);
    }
    updateResults();
    // This function is running before the code above
    // ...so I actually get no results
}
```

How to run the `updateResults()` function at the moment when results are already taken from database?

Comment: You have to put updateResults(); at the place of "//some code here"

Comment: all your script is uncorrect. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: @Gael: why is "all the script" incorrect exactly ?

Comment: Excuse me if I was a bit brutal! httpReq is not defined (or outside the function, which is not very clean), you check the readyState before sending the request (although, as you allow it to be equal to 0, it will work).

Comment: I've edited the thread for you to understand how I'm creating the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the code should be like this:

```
function getResults() {
    httpReq.open("GET",'../search.php?blablabla',true);
    httpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (httpReq.readyState == 4) {
            // Some code here
            updateResults();
        }
    };
    httpReq.send(null);
}
```